# Fluid dynamics of a balloon

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, rocket-science, viscosity

This is a question which might not seem relevant to physics, but I was always curious if the shape of the balloon were to be not the shape that we all know of, when we release the tip will air flow out at a different rate?

[image]

For instance in each of the above images of the balloon, given that they all have the same type of air molecule inside, when the ends are released, will air all flow out of these balloons at the same rate and therefore default equally ? If yes why ? If not also why ? Could anyone kindly help me explain this please?

Answer (score 1):

Air will flow out at a rate that to the first order depends on:

- the size of the opening
- the pressure in the balloon

The balloons may have a different shape, but it's possible for them to all be at the same pressure.

Also, the pressure will not be constant as air is released.   So there's not going to be any simple relationship between shape and airflow.